# UIView loaded from xib as subview : How to set the frame/size properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a small problem with my iphone app (I am quite new to iphone programmation even if I had already done objective-c before).

I have an UIView named `centerView` in my main window.
I have created a singleton subclass of UIViewController (let's call it `FooViewController`) linked with a xib file. My goal is to load the associated view as a subview (of centerView using the whole frame of centerView).

Problem : The view controlled by FooViewController does not use the frame of its superview.

I have tried to add :

- `self.view.frame = self.view.superview.frame` in the "custom initialisation" part of the initWithNib... method of FooViewController
- `[[[FooViewController sharedController] view] setFrame:centerView.frame]` when I add the view to centerview (`[centerView addSubView:[[FooViewController sharedController] view]]`) (I have tried before and after this line)

But I can't get the good behavior (i.e. the good size). There are multiple questions related to this kind of problems but I was unable to find my answer in them so :

- Do you know how I can solve that ?
- *[optional] How did the instanciation of a UIViewController linked with a xib works ? There must be a resource file where the name of the xib is indicated ? Or maybe does it looks for a xib with the same name as the class ?*

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When loading from a NIB, a view is loaded in the view controller's `loadView` method, not in the initializer. Since you shouldn't really override `loadView`, esp. if you are loading it from a NIB, you should try doing #1 (`self.view.frame = self.view.superview.frame`) in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. Of course, you should ensure that the view is added to a superview by the time you execute this statement. You also need to make sure that the superview's frame has been correctly set by this time.

Another place where you can try this is in the `viewWillAppear:` method. Most probably your view's super view will have been set up properly by then.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I have tried to put the code concerning the frame setting in viewWillAppear but it does seems to do anything. Actually the problem comes from an other part : superview is null even in viewWillAppear (but self.view.superview.frame does not create any segfault...). I will investigate this point.

Comment: In obj-c, if the receiver is nil, it will accept any method, and return nil (I think). That's why you don't get an segfault even if self.view.superview is nil.